# Geometry: formula how to get $x,y$ of $P$ on circle.

Tags: geometry

Looking for the position $x$ and $y$ of a point $P$ on circle, knowing that:

- The circle has center at $x=63.992$ and $y=27.727$, radius of $12$.
- Line segment A (circle center to point P) and line segment B (circle center to bottom of circle) make an angle of $70°$.

Like [this](https://mathmonks.com/circle/parametric-equation-of-circle) but $P$ and $Y$ coordinates are on the opposite side. Is there a single formula that works no matter where $p$ is placed on the circle and position of the reference.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/qNSxo.jpg

If i try to use the formula on the site:

> $x = h + r \cos \theta$
> $y = k + r \sin \theta$

I have :
$Px = 63.992 + 12\cos( 70°) = 68.096$
$Py = 27.727 + 12\sin( 70°) = 39.003$

But this is not correct when I measure by hand (tape measurement).

And by the way do you have a website where we can easily simulate all those position possibilities ?

Comment: It's probably simple but I forgot all those basic geometry because probably getting old.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The website probably always has the angle $\theta$ starting at the positive x-axis. So you might want to check with your tape measurement whether $\theta = 200^\circ = 3\cdot 90^\circ - 70^\circ$ works better than the $70^\circ$.

Comment: you are right the angle start always from the same place and anti-clockwise. Here a better visualization of Parametric Equation of Circle with drag-able point: https://mathopenref.com/coordparamcircle.html

Comment: But θ=160°=360° - 90° - 70°

Comment: I think $360^\circ - 90^\circ - 70^\circ = 200^\circ$

Comment: lol your are right, actually because of the reversed axe Y the triangle will correspond to the one on the top left of the graph. Which make θ=160°= 90° + 70°. So i made mistake on calculation.